# Overloading "*" Operator for custom SmartPointer

Tags: visual-c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

I am trying to directly access integer from a pointer class, by overloading * operator, but it seems VC++ 10 is not allowing it. Kindly help:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int MAX7 = 10;

struct node{
    int value;
    node *next;
};
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;
int count = 0;

class SmartPointer{
public:
    SmartPointer(){
    }
    int push(int i){
        if(count == MAX7)   return 0;

        if(head == NULL){
            head = new node();
            current = head;
            head -> next = NULL;
            head -> value = i;
            count = 1;
        }
        else{
            struct node *ptr = head;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)    ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new node;
            ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = NULL;
            ptr->value = i;
            count++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    void Display(){
        node *ptr = head;
        while(ptr != NULL){
            cout << ptr->value << "(" << ptr << ")";
            if( ptr == current )
                cout << "*";
            cout << ", ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        } 
    }

    int operator *(){
        if(current == NULL) return -1;
        struct node *ptr = current;
        return ptr->value;
    }
};

int main(){
    SmartPointer *sp;
    sp = new SmartPointer();
    sp->push(99);
    for(int i=100; i<120; i++){
        if(sp->push(i))
            cout << "\nPushing ("<<i<<"): Successful!";
        else
            cout << "\nPushing ("<<i<<"): Failed!";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    sp->Display();

    int i = *sp;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Error#
1>test7.cpp(71): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'SmartPointer' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer:

```
int i = **sp;
```

You should not allocate objects with new. Your code looks like java. In C++, you must delete everything you allocate with new. In C++ you can write:

```
SmartPointer sp;
sp.push(99);
int i = *sp;
```

Answer (score 1):

`sp` is not a smart pointer - it's a plain old dumb pointer to `SmartPointer` class. `*sp` uses built-in dereference operator, producing an lvalue of `SmartPointer` type. It does not call `SmartPointer::operator*()` - for that, you need to write `**sp` (two stars).

It's not at all clear why you want to allocate `SmartPointer` instance on the heap. That's an unusual thing to want to do (also too, you leak it). I'm pretty sure you would be better off with

```
SmartPointer sp;
sp.push(99);
```

and so on.